# What SELinux type should I apply on my Unix socket?

Tags: nginx, centos, centos7, socket, selinux

I have a Gunicorn socket file: `/opt/rtd/gunicorn/run.sock`. I need nginx to be able to open this socket and write to it.

When I run `sesearch --allow -s httpd_t | grep unix_stream_socket` I noticed that *httpd_t* is allowed to connect to sockets of type *httpd_t*. But when I try to apply that I get:

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_t "/opt/rtd/gunicorn/run.sock"
ValueError: Type httpd_t is invalid, must be a file or device type
```

I've tried other types I found from sesearch, for example *httpd_sys_script_t* or even *passenger_t*. Same result.

What should I set the type to?

I would prefer not to have to create additional policies to allow more than necessary. There must be a way to allow httpd_t to read from a file socket with existing policies in CentOS 7.2, right?

Comment: What is the output of `file  /opt/rtd/gunicorn/run.sock`?

Comment: Have exactly this problem trying to allow nginx access to proxy to a server listening on a unix socket.  `file` reports the type as `socket`.  I wonder if fcontext doesn't apply to UNIX sockets?